# Reload page using jQuery based on table values

Tags: jquery, sql, time, settimeout, setinterval

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & have an interval that runs on the page to check a SQL table every so many seconds for new data.  The page itself is going to be up (virtually) all the time.

There's a table available that has starting & ending times on it.  The fields are in a SQL 2012 database and are defined as `TIME` fields, and the time is in 24 hour format. An example of what the ending times would look like are:  `15:59:59.999`, `23:59:59.999`, and `07:59:59.999`. Beginning times are `08:00:00.000`, `16:00:00.000` and `00:00:00.000` respectively.

I want to refresh the page (force the page to reload itself) sometime **after** those ending times. Not yet sure how long afterward, but assume 3 minutes.  There is also the chance that there will be a popup page present, which would need to be closed and could re-open when the main page is refreshed/reloaded.  Also, even though the page should be up, I can't assume that it was opened at the beginning time.

As part of the page load, I would re-query the table & get a new ending time.  Also, should the page be closed and re-opened, that would also re-query and get a new ending time.

Is it better to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: `setInterval` will make it run every X seconds while `setTimeout` makes it run once after X time has passed.  If the entire page is reloading (including the reloading script) `setTimeout` would likely be better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only wanting to refresh the page, I believe you would want to use setTimeout. setInterval executes an expression every [interval] seconds, setTimeout is a one time execution after a given amount of time. I believe the best way to accomplish what you want to do is incorporate the time calculation on the backend. That is, in your PHP (or whatever server side language you are using) get the current time, figure out the amount of time between the current time and the "ending time" (then add 3 minutes), and pass that variable to your setTimeout function. You can do this on page load or make an ajax call as soon as the page loads if you dont mind the couple seconds that ajax will take. This way, every time the page is loaded it is updated with the current amount of time until "ending time".